# Calculate data from cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

l am trying to collect and SUM data from a workbook.

The data I need is calculated from cells in one sheet of the workbook. I will display the result with "value only format".

How can I shorten the code and make it run faster?

The workbook where I collect data is Test.xlsm and I have around 30 items.

```vb
Sub Test1()
'
' Test1 Macro
   
    Dim Slaw150 As Variant
    Dim Slaw200 As Variant
    Dim Slaw300 As Variant
    Dim Slaw400 As Variant
    
    Slaw150 = "=SUM('[Test.xlsm]Test'!$CO$66:$CS$66,'[Test.xlsm]Test'!$CO$88:$CS$88,'[Test.xlsm]Test'!$CO$95:$CS$95)"
    Slaw200 = "=SUM('[Test.xlsm]Test'!$CO$67:$CS$67,'[Test.xlsm]Test'!$CO$89:$CS$89,'[Test.xlsm]Test'!$CO$96:$CS$96)"
    Slaw300 = "=SUM('[Test.xlsm]Test'!$CO$68:$CS$68,'[Test.xlsm]Test'!$CO$90:$CS$90,'[Test.xlsm]Test'!$CO$97:$CS$97)"
    Slaw400 = "=SUM('[Test.xlsm]Test'!$CO$69:$CS$69,'[Test.xlsm]Test'!$CO$91:$CS$91,'[Test.xlsm]Test'!$CO$98:$CS$98)"
    
    With Range("C42")
        .Value = Slaw150
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    
    With Range("C43")
        .Value = Slaw200
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    
    With Range("C44")
        .Value = Slaw300
        .Value = .Value
    End With
      
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are using VBA for that, can't you just copy the formulae in the cells?

Comment: HI, I used the formula then when file Test.xlsm update by using macro, an error occur and break the Test.xlsm macro. That why I need a macro for my file instead of the formula.

If you know how to activate the formula only when you want it can solve my problem as well. 

Thanks so much

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please, test the  next way:

```
Sub TestSUMM()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, rngSUM As Range, arrSUM, i As Long
   
   Set sh = Workbooks("Test.xlsm").Sheets("Test")
   Set rngSUM = sh.Range("CO66:CS69,CO88:CS91,CO95:CS98") 'The whole discontinuous range
   ReDim arrSUM(1 To 4, 1 To 1)   'ReDim the array to keep processing result
   
   For i = 1 To rngSUM.rows.Count 'iterate between the discontinuous range rows and summarize them:
        arrSUM(i, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(rngSUM.rows(i))
   Next i
   
   sh.Range("I41").Resize(4).Value = arrSUM 'drop the array content at once
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your helping. However, the Code " Set sh = Workbooks("Test.xlsm").sheet("Test") " is show the error " Run-time erroe '9' Subscript out of range". That I believe that it can not detect the Test.xlsm file. Can you help me out please !

Comment: @Minh Nguyen It should be `Workbooks("Test.xlsm").Sheets("Test")`...